# Facing Error While getting backend Document in xpages (SSJS) On Lotus Notes Client

Tags: xpages

I am facing issue in workflow application developed on xpages using SSJS. I have status field which is text field containing status 0 to 20. When document is send back to initiator and status value is set to 0.  Concerned initiator try to re-submit the request system generates error while accessing values using datasource. Unable to get backend document value. The same code works well in browser. Can you please guide me what is the issue with my code accessing backend value from client. 
Following is the error:

```
Unexpected Run Time Error
[TypeError] Exception occurred calling method NotesDocument.getItemValue(string) null

var mTitle = leaveDoc.getDocument().getItemValueString("Type");

if (mTitle == "Cancel")
{
return "Leave Application Cancellation Form"
}
else
{
return "Leave Application Form"
}
```

Please have a look at it and guide me.

Thanks

Comment: [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method NotesDocument.getItemValue(string) null translates to: NotesDocument object you are calling the method on is null. So it depends on what is before that call. Post the code.

Comment: Without your code I can't check the errorline

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. Same code works perfectly fine in browser. I am using datasource to get backend document which is creating problem when document is send back to initiator otherwise it working fine on both. where leaveDoc is datasource.

Comment: More code! How did you define leaveDoc exactly? Your UNID mechanism might be faulty!

Comment: leaveDoc is datasource. its works perfectly fine on browser and notes in right case scenario. if its send back and comes on initial stage and re-submitted its throws an error that leaveDoc not found? I don't know what is the issue as same code works on my machine without any issue.